# Add Header/Title to telerik Radgrid?

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have recently started working with telerik controls. I need to add a header above the radGrid like

Title: ABC    Name: XYZ
Column1 Column2 Clolumn3 Column4
abc                def                  ghi                    klm

Should I call any event or is there any other approach to do this? I would be exporting this grid, so I would want these details to be exported to excel but not visible in the UI.

Answer (score 5):

to set the title in your grid you have to set only one property in your grid.

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Caption = "Title: ABC Name: XYZ";
```

OR

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/262215-merge-column-headers.aspx